# How to read a file from a nested zip archive using Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to read a txt file that is nested within a parent zip file. The folder structure is like below:

**Parent Zip File:** `ParentFile.zip`

**Contents:** `ParentFolder/Subfolder1/Subfolder2/File1.zip`

`File1.zip` contains `File1.txt` which I am trying to read in memory. I checked the documentation for `Archive::Zip and Archive::Zip::MemberRead`. I couldn't find a method that returns a new zip object from the members list so that i could use the below method.

```
$fh  = Archive::Zip::MemberRead->new($zipObj, "File1.txt");
```

The file I am trying to read is 200MB and I need to loop through 300 such files.  `ParentFile.zip` is located on a network drive and i only have read access to it. I am trying to find out how i can extract the zip file to my local drive. I found below approaches but doesn't seem to help when i have a nested structure.

```
use strict;
use Archive::Zip; 

my $destinationDirectory = 'C:\test'; 
my $zipObj = Archive::Zip->new('\\NetworkDrive\ParentFile.zip'); #SourceFile Path
#Cannot do below - No write permission on the network drive 
$zipObj->extractMember('ParentFolder/Subfolder1/Subfolder2/File1.zip')     

#Cannot do below as well since i have a folder structure
foreach my $member ($zip-> members()){
    my $extractName = $member->fileName;         
    $member->extractToFileNamed("$destinationDirectory/$extractName");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [IO::Uncompress::Unzip](http://search.cpan.org/%7Epmqs/IO-Compress-2.074/lib/IO/Uncompress/Unzip.pm) to work with a nested zip file without having to uncompress and store any of the enclosing zip files to disk.

Here is an example to show how it works.

In my test setup I have a zip file called `outer.zip` that contains `inner.zip`.

```
$ unzip -l outer.zip 
Archive:  outer.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      185  03-23-2018 12:53   inner.zip
---------                     -------
      185                     1 file
```

`inner.zip` contains the file we want to get access to.

```
$ unzip -l inner.zip 
Archive:  inner.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       14  03-23-2018 12:53   payload.txt
---------                     -------
       14                     1 file
```

In this instance it just contains a few lines of text.

```
$ cat payload.txt 
line 1
line 2
```

The script below will read the payload data from the `inner zip` and write to `output.txt`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use IO::Uncompress::Unzip qw(unzip) ;

my $outer = "outer.zip";
my $inner = "inner.zip";
my $data = "payload.txt";
my $output = "output.txt";

my $z = new IO::Uncompress::Unzip $outer, Name => $inner
    or die "Cannot open $outer\n";

unzip $z => $output, Name => $data
    or die "Cannot unzip $inner";
```

This is what I see in `output.txt`

```
$ cat output.txt 
line 1
line 2
```

**Points to Note**

1. The `$z` object returned from the `IO::Uncompress::Unzip` constructor is a Perl filehandle that will read `outer.zip` in *streaming mode*. The `Name => $inner` parameters tell it that we are only interested in the `inner.zip` entry in `outer.zip`.
2. The `$z` filehandle is then used in a call to the `unzip` method to read the `payload.txt` entry of `inner.zip`.
3. [IO::Uncompress::Unzip](http://search.cpan.org/%7Epmqs/IO-Compress-2.074/lib/IO/Uncompress/Unzip.pm) is a *streaming* uncompressor. That means you get the ability to access a nested zip file (potentially to any depth), without having to store any data from the enclosing zip files to disk.
4. The use of [IO::Uncompress::Unzip](http://search.cpan.org/%7Epmqs/IO-Compress-2.074/lib/IO/Uncompress/Unzip.pm) does not mean that you get access to a nested zip file without having to incur the cost of uncompressing the enclosing zip file. In this case the data from all the nested layers of zip files is uncompressed in-memory a bit at a time as it is needed.
5. Running a streaming unzip does come with a health warning. Most zip files can be uncompressed in *streaming* mode, but there are exceptions. Handle with care.

### Recursive Uncompression

Taking the above example one step further, you can use the fact that the Perl `IO::Compress::*` modules all return a real Perl filehandle to create a recursive script that will walk well-formed nested zip files to any depth.

This script below, `nested-unzip`, uses a derivative module of `IO::Uncompress::Unzip` called [Archive::Zip::SimpleUnzip](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Zip::SimpleUnzip) to do the work. All it does is list the members of all the zip files found.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Zip::StreamedUnzip qw($StreamedUnzipError) ;

sub walk
{
    my $unzip  = shift ;
    my @unzip_path = @{ shift() };

    while (my $member = $unzip->next())
    {
        my $name = $member->name();

        print "  " x @unzip_path . "$name\n" ;
        if ($name =~ /\.zip$/i)
        {
            if ($member->isEncrypted())
            {
                print "  " x @unzip_path . "$name ENCRYPTED\n" ;
                next;
            }

            my $fh = $member->open();
            my $newunzip = new Archive::Zip::StreamedUnzip $fh
                or die "Cannot open '$name': $StreamedUnzipError";
            walk($newunzip, [@unzip_path, $name]);
        }
    }
}

my $zipfile = $ARGV[0];

my $unzip = new Archive::Zip::StreamedUnzip $zipfile
            or die "Cannot open '$zipfile': $StreamedUnzipError";

print "$zipfile\n" ;
walk($unzip, [$zipfile]) ;
```

Running that against `outer.zip` gives

```
$ perl nested-unzip oute.zip
outer.zip
  inner.zip
    payload.txt
```

Comment: `IO::Compress::Unzip` can be a convenient way to read data from a zip file, and it may *appear* to avoid decompressing the files, but there is no way to read zipped data without decompressing it and this is just an illusion

Comment: That is correct - there will still be the cost of uncompressing part of the outer and inner zip files - that cannot be avoided. This technique avoids the disk I/O when uncompressing the outer zip file by streaming it directly to the code that handles the uncompression of the inner zip files. That is what I read as the requirement from the original question.

Answer (score 1):

200MB isn't a big file, and you shouldn't be anticipating bottlenecks in your code before you have done some timings

`File1.zip` has been doubly-compressed into `ParentFile.zip`. There is no way to extract the information from the former without expanding at least the relevant part of the latter

Unless `File1.zip` is enormous (the zip format allows many gigabytes of simple data to be compressed to a few hundred bytes) you should simply extract the entire file and process it in a second step

If you're desperate, then there are ways to extract a list of the items within a zip file without access to the entire contents, but I don't think that is going to help you

Comment: my script needs to read 360+ zip files of 200MB each. I also do not have write access to this archive location. All i can think of at the moment is to extract the zip to my temp location but there seems to be no options to extract to a specific location.

Comment: Please add information to your question rather than accumulating comments about it. What is the problem with reading 360 200MB files? Have you timed it? Unless those files are networked I wouldn't expect more than a few seconds delay. If you're being asked for a millisecond response time then you must report that it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

> The file I am trying to read is 200MB and I don't want to extract.

You'll probably have to extract it.

If the inner ZIP file has been deflated, there's no choice -- you can't seek within a deflated stream, and ZIP archives cannot be read without seeking. (The table of contents is stored at the end of the archive.)

If the inner ZIP file is stored (i.e, not compressed), it might be technically possible to treat the stored content as a ZIP archive, but I'm not aware of any way to make Archive::Zip do that.

Comment: *"you can't seek within a deflated stream"* A zip archive file may be read from the start. There is a small initial header followed by a series of file entities that can stand alone. The trailing data isn't required.

Comment: The trailing data includes the directory. There's no way to reliably look up files by name without that -- while each file header contains the name of the file, there's no way of knowing whether that file is included in the directory. (It may have been deleted and left in situ.)